# seleção múltipla input checkbox materialize não funciona

Tags: php, materialize

Estou usando a biblioteca Materialize, pegando os dados do banco e listando no front-end, porém a seleção múltipla não funciona:

```html
<div class="row">
 <form action="#">
  <span>
   <?
   $sql = "SELECT * from $ufEstab where cidade = '{$cidadeEstab}' group by bairro";
   $query = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
   while ( $ln = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {?>
    <div class="col s4">
     <input value="<?= utf8_encode($ln['bairro']);?>" type="checkbox" name="bairro" id="test5" />
     <label for="test5"><?= utf8_encode($ln['bairro']);?></label>
    </div>
   <? }//fim do while bairros ?>
  </span>
  <button class="btn">Cadastrar bairros</button>
 </form>
</div><!--row-->
```

Comment: Acho melhor você utilizar um select com o atributo multiple.
<select multiple>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que não está funcionando ?

Comment: Funciona sim, só que você está mandando o PHP definir todos os checkboxs com o mesmo valor em name (bairro), portanto, na hora de enviar o formulário, um elemento irá sobrepor o outro de forma a parecer apenas um único elemento.

Answer (score 1):

Troque de:

`<input value="<?= utf8_encode($ln['bairro']);?>" type="checkbox" name="bairro" id="test5" />`

para:

`<input value="<?= utf8_encode($ln['bairro']);?>" type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" id="test5" />`

Adicionando ao **name** do input o `[]`, ao submitar o form ele será enviado como um array de multi escolhas.